# Android SharedPreferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am tring to solve a problem very strange

I have an app that was working great in all of my testing devices, after a factory reset on Nexus 5, When it try to get an `int` from the SharedPreferences with code

`LEVEL_MAXIMO_ALCANZADO = sp.getInt(SP_NIVEL_JUEGO_MAXIMO, 1);`

It give me an String (but only in Nexus 5, in other devices it give me the int but in my nexus 5 is causing an exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` )

If I get the value of the String with the code

```
String prueba = sp.getString(SP_NIVEL_JUEGO_MAXIMO, "1");
```

I get a value of `5t+SNTiVFHA=`

I dont have any idea why this only pass in nexus 5 after factory reset

If someone can give a tip to follow it will be awesome, I am lost at this point

Code - ( ctx is a Context Object)

```
 public static SharedPreferences sp;
 public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  if(sp == null) sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  if(editor  == null) editor = sp.edit();

  editor.putInt(SP_DINERO, DINERO);
  editor.commit();
```

**Additional info**

I also tryed to unistall app and reboot device

I used ObscuredSharedPreferences a class which encrypt them and in that class it give me pad block corrupted exception, then I swap to SharedPreferences but same error

I made the factory reset due to an issue where my phonne said that it was full when only 5gb was used

so maybe is a memory issue on the device?

Comment: use a helper class : https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper

Comment: Can you post code where you are saving the value and also where the sp object is made.

Comment: The issue you are saying seems impossible, so for more clearity can you post code where you are saving the value and also where the sp object is made

Comment: Updated with the code , I also tryed to rebot the device

Comment: I added more info, the code should be fine since it works on other devices and before the factory reset it worked on nexus 5 as well

Comment: @AndroidMechanic I was using ObscuredSharedPreferences that encrypt them, and then i swap to SharedPreferences to be ensure the class wasnt a problem

Comment: Did you try to use String.valueOf(1) .. maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a Reset ( Wipe cache and wipe data, and factory reset from bootloader) and now It is working again

I think that the memory got corrupted and It was failing.